# Printer recommendations?

Tags: print-design, print-production

I have been using online printer suppliers previously but I am wanting to invest some money into a good quality printer so I can print business cards (on normal, Gloss & matt card) and flyers...

I am wondering what printer would be best for this sort of work?

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, a laser printer is your best option.

It looks like the folks at Wirecutter have determined the [HP Color LaserJet Pro M254DW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073R2WVKB) to be one of the better ones.

### Wirecutter Review

https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-laser-printer/

### Pros

- More consistent print quality than inkjet
- Can sit unused for longer periods; no clogged cartridges and less wasted consumables.
- More durable prints. Toner is more or less water-resistant and will not bleed like ink.

### Cons

- Expensive. The toner cartridges are often more than ink and the technology and machine are just generally more costly to purchase and repair.

### Food for thought

While it is nice to have the convenience of an at-home printer to fine-tune work and have instant-availability, consider developing a relationship with a local independent print company. They'll probably be a little more expensive than an office supply chain, but you'll likely get a better quality business resource and may have greater latitude to work with you on price if you're a regular customer.

The reality is, most at-home printers are not production machines. I would suspect they will do very well for a couple color copies of reports and photographs here and there, but if you're planning to print hundreds of designs on a regular basis, you could end up spending a lot of money on toner and the machine will likely break down at some point.

There is also a lot of finishing work in flyers and business cards. You need to cut all of those things to size. That is extremely time consuming work when done sheet by sheet. A print shop can cut stacks of cards/flyers in a few minutes.

How much is your time worth and is cutting sheets of paper the best use of it? There's no right answer, just something to think about.